# jQuery $(document).ready() not firing with excel Response Content Type

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Is there any way to get jQuery $(document).ready() to fire when the content type is Excel?  i.e. browser opens excel download.   I figure probably not.  Using ASP.NET C# server-side.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

Comment: Response from `ajax` call , page load ? Please illuminate . Thanks

Comment: No it's doing a synchronous post afaik.  That code is from the C# code-behind function.